# Can I use $wpdb for my custom tables in the WordPress database?

Tags: customization, database, wpdb

I am building a custom application based on WordPress.  I have my custom tables in the WP database.  Can I use $wpdb to work with them, or is that class solely for the WP related tables?

For example, If I have a database that keeps up with dogs and cats, and I create a custom table named animals (animalid, animal_type, etc.).  Do I use $wpdb?

I don't know if "interacting with the WordPress database" with $wpdb is intended solely for the stock tables or not.

EDIT:  I created the tables by hand with MySQL Workbench.  They were tables upsized from Microsoft Access.  I have not "informed" WordPress of their existence or know if I should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Straight from [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

> The $wpdb object is not limited to the default tables created by WordPress; it can be used to read data from any table in the WordPress database (such as custom plugin tables). For example to SELECT some information from a custom table called "mytable", you can do the following.

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
```

Comment: But should I be using the custom $wpdb->some_method, like       ->update(), insert(), etc. or do I use get_results and use raw SQL?  I prefer SQL.

Comment: I would use the built in methods where possible because that's why they exist but if you prefer a more raw approach you can use the get_results method.

Comment: I register tables by adding them to the $wpdb object as it makes them easily available: $wpdb->my_custom_table = "{$wpdb->prefix}my_custom_table" and then I only ever use $wpdb->my_custom_table which allows the table name to be changed to anything the site owner likes.